# Create new pages for docman in joomla from a C# program

Tags: c#, joomla

I was volunteered to write a application that will take a mp3 file, upload it to the server create a document that references the file and fills out a template and uploads the document for the web admin to approve it.

I am a fairly competent c# developer but I have never even touched web development stuff. I have no clue where to begin

They are running Joomla 1.5 with DocMan 1.4. I have no php programming experience but I have done java and c# so when I poked around the API documentation some of it seems familiar.

Any point in the right direction for books or online guides would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does Joomla have an API or web service you can point to with your app?  Maybe you can use the Webclient in .Net and post the file and pertinent information up to the Joomla server.

UPDATE:

I found this [XML-RPC lib in .Net](http://www.xml-rpc.net/).  If you have seen this yet, here's a link [for Joomla's Metaweblog API](http://www.waltercedric.com/joomla-mainmenu-247/303-how-to/1271-joomla-xmlrpc-.html).

Comment: That's what I was looking in to when i said it "looked familiar"

Comment: The biggest issue is the API on their site is more geared towards developing Joomla modules not doing inter-op with outside programs.

Comment: XML-RPC looks perfect. I have used SOAP with some of my .net projects. This should do it.